# What would you call a collection class which represents a set but where the order matters?

Tags: language-agnostic, collections, naming-conventions, naming

A collection that can have duplicates and where the order matters is called a **List**.
A collection that can have duplicates and where the order doesn't matter is called a **Bag**.
A collection that cannot have duplicates and where the order doesn't matter is called a **Set**.

What then for the fourth combination; what would you call the class of collection that cannot have duplicates and where the order matters?

If you can link to an example of your suggested name (the more widely-used the better), please do so.

Comment: Do you mean explicit ordering (like a list) or implicit ordering (i.e. based on elements' sort order)?

Comment: Explicit ordering, such as in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would name it an **ordered set**

Comment: But that doesn't say if it's implicit or explicit ordering. That's a critical distinction.

Comment: I would say that explicit order (sorted data for example) does not have to do with data structure(how it is stored), it is related to data functionality (what it is used for). I'd say that he refers to only implicit order

Comment: My point is that the name doesn't make this clear, it could be interpreted either way.

Answer (score 0):

How about `List-Ordered Set`.

Example: Java's Apache Commons Collections library ([class docs](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/set/ListOrderedSet.html)) (now obsolete since Java introduced its own `LinkedHashSet` class).